# Is there a word for a number with commas?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, numbers

For example:
1000000 is a "number"
and
1,000,000 is a "number"

Is there a way to tell someone to use "______ numbers" without saying to use "numbers with a comma after every thousand, million, etc.?"

Comment: I'd say it's just the simplest and best-known version of a [formatted number](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22formatted+number%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Do you want a more specific term? Does it matter if the format includes a decimal point and further digits? What about a leading currency symbol?

Comment: In single word answer, "no".

Comment: @Hot Licks: Assuming I couldn't ask for clarification, if I were told to write something using *formatted numbers* then *faute de mieux* I'd assume "with commas" (and a decimal point if my numbers were money to the penny).

Comment: You should simply say to use thousands separators in numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following sentence is a professional request:

Please use *[delimiters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter)* with large numbers.

> A delimiter is a sequence of **one** or more characters used to specify
>   the boundary between separate, independent regions in plain text or
>   other data streams.

*Delimiters* are particularly helpful in *[mathematical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping)* notation:

> For ease of reading, numbers with many digits may be divided into
>   groups using **a delimiter**.

Source: *en.wikipedia.org* **Emphasis** mine

Comment: No: paired quotes, parenthesess, and brackets are **delimiters**; commas and semicolons are **separators**; and periods (full stops), question marks, and exclamation points are **terminators**. See the differences now?

Comment: Yes, @tchrist, I appreciate this fine distinction of punctuation in English composition, but in mathematical notation (and many cases of data management), delimiters are employed one at a time. The preponderance of definitions, including the two I cited, allow for the solitary [delimiter](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=delimiter+definition&spell=1).

Comment: Not when people are being careful about it, it doesn’t. The string ":a:b:c:" has 5 colon-separated fields, 3 colon-delimited fields, and 4 colon-terminated fields. These are utterly different. I don’t want anybody who believes that 3 = 4 = 5 anywhere near my data, because they’ll just screw it up with their carelessness. Every single technical specification makes clear which of those **MUST** be used. Only vague hand-waving talk by people who have no idea what they are actually talking about ever equates those. You cannot do real technical work with such silliness—because it is unprofessional.

Comment: Agreed, @tchrist, in some situations the *fine distinction* is important :-)

Comment: I ended up using the verbiage "correctly delimited numbers" as I was trying to describe numbers that are separated by thousands (or whichever separation your language uses) as a blanket term.

Comment: From Harry Bellefonte's [*Man Piaba*](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/harrybelafonte/manpiaba.html): "It was clear as mud, but it covered the ground..." :-)

Answer (score 4):

Commonly *"thousands separator"* is the name of the comma in this format; that doesn't translate nicely to an adjective, so perhaps you could rephrase your statement slightly to tell them to use *"numbers with thousands separators"* (rather than the clumsy "thousands separated numbers").

Comment: Note that this is probably only true in locales that use delimiters to indicate thousands; not all of them do. For example, [in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system), five digit numbers and larger are grouped by digit pairs rather than triples.  I'm not sure what they would be called there, but it seems likely that they aren't "thousands separators".

Comment: @Mark Those ARE NOT delimiters. Those are separators, as this answer properly calls them.

Comment: Ummm... OK.  They're still likely not called *thousands* separators.  Since, y'know, they're not thousands.

Comment: Whether they're used or not is obviously locale-specific, the name of them is not. Even in India, if you were describing the commas that other locales use to separate the thousands, then the commonly used term is as I describe in my answer.